# How do you show that $7a^2 - 12b^2 = 8c^2$ has no integer solutions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do you show that $7a^2 - 12b^2 = 8c^2$ has no integer solutions

---

When $x = a/c$ and $y = b/c$ then $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ I believe.

If we use mod5, and neither $a,b,c$ is divisible by 5 then $7a^2 - 12b^2$ can have remainder 1 or 4 and $8c^2$ can only have remainder 2 or 3. But if either $a$ or $b$ is divisible by 5 then $7a^2 - 12b^2$ will have remainder 2 or 3.

I've considered using mod7 so $-12b^2$ would have remainder either $1,2,$ or $4.$ But $8c^2$ can have remainder 1,2 or 4 as well.

I'm not really sure how to go about this, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

WLOG $(a,c)=1$

Take modulo $\pmod3$

$$a^2\equiv2c^2\pmod3$$

But for any integer $d,$

$$d^2\equiv0,1\pmod3\not\equiv2$$

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using mod $4$, a is divisible by $2$
Let $a = 2k$

$7k^2 - 3b^2 = 2c^2$

HINT: GO mod 3 and use that $t^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod 3$ for all positive integers t

Comment: Didn't see @lab Bhattacharjee's answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, assume that $\gcd (a,b,c) = 1$ as you did.

Taking modulo $3$ gives $a^2 \equiv 2c^2 \pmod 3$.

As $n^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod 3$, we must have $a \equiv c \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

Hence $3 \nmid b$, and $a^2 \equiv c^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$.

Now taking modulo $9$, we have:

$$-3b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$$

suggesting that $3 \mid b$, which is a contradiction.